# Can Flink attach multiple jobs to Stream local envirnoment with Web Ui by java code?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, bigdata

Can Flink attach multiple jobs to Stream local envirnoment with Web Ui by java code?

my code is like this

```
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(config); 
env.addSource(...); 
env.addSink(...); 
env.execute("stream job1");
```

What I would like to do is to loop through this and attach job2 job3 to the same environment with web ui managment. How can this be done in java code?

I tried to use `env2 = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(),` 
 but it seems like the new job2 is not attatch to env I created before.

please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to re-use the created `StreamExecutionEnvironment` which you have stored in `env`.

`StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI` won't set the respective context environment factory. Therefore, `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment` won't return the created local environment which has the Web UI enabled.

Comment: yes, I did try to resue it, but I get error, saying that the address bind is already in use, I think env try to use the same jobmanager address for some reason. I will update my questoin with the code and error message soon. Thanks for help.

Comment: You're right. The problem is that the underlying `LocalStreamEnvironment` creates for each `execute` call a new `LocalFlinkMiniCluster` using the same ports. This might cause the problems. Are you trying to concurrently run Flink jobs on the same local cluster?

Comment: Yes I am trying to run multiple jobs in one local local cluster.

Comment: Concurrently or one after each other?

Comment: In fact, at first, I was running multiple LocalFlinkMiniCluster on different prot, each of them has only one job. However, it consume a lot of RAM spend, I am think to run all the job in one LocalFlinkMiniCluster.

Comment: I try to run them concurrently , not one after each other

Comment: I think maybe I should use JobClient to submit multiple jobs?

Comment: Running them concurrently won't work because the the `LocalFlinkMiniCluster` will only be started with as many slots as are needed for the first job to run. What you can do though, is to start a `LocalFlinkMiniCluster` and then use a `RemoteStreamEnvironment` to submit jobs to this cluster. However, be aware that you have to start the cluster with as many slots as you need for all your jobs to be run concurrently. Alternatively you can also combine all jobs into one. Then the operators can share slots.

Comment: Thank you Till Rohmann, I will try the RemoteStreamEnviroment solution first.

Comment: I tried to use RemoteStreamEnvironment to submit the task but I can not connect the jobManager of the LocalFlinkMiniCluster, I got this  Trying to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:29011
2017-05-11 14:06:48.308  INFO 9496 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.a.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils    : Failed to connect from address 'tong-iQware/127.0.1.1': Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-05-11 14:06:48.309  INFO 9496 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.a.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils    : Failed to connect from address '/127.0.0.1': Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143997/discussion-between-zt1983811-and-till-rohrmann).

Answer (score 1):

It seems working that (with single `LocalStreamEnvironment`) one do multiple

```
DataStream stream = env.addSource(...);
...
stream.addSink(...);
```

And finally

```
env.execute();
```

However this seems to be one job with multiple source->sink flow, instead of multiple jobs.

---

OK. The hack here for submitting jobs to local cluster.

In main thread, start local cluster with some config

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setLong(TaskManagerOptions.MANAGED_MEMORY_SIZE, -1L);
configuration.setInteger(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_NUMBER_TASK_MANAGER, 2);
configuration.setInteger(ConfigConstants.TASK_MANAGER_NUM_TASK_SLOTS, 100);

// start cluster
LocalFlinkMiniCluster exec = new LocalFlinkMiniCluster(configuration, true);
exec.start();
// sleep or wait for all job finishes
Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Then in other threads, submit job (with `exec` from main thread)

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
DataStream stream = env.addSource(...);
...
stream.addSink(...);

StreamGraph streamGraph = env.getStreamGraph();
streamGraph.setJobName(name);
JobGraph jobGraph = streamGraph.getJobGraph();
exec.submitJobAndWait(jobGraph, true);
```

Note `StreamExecutionEnvironment` is only used to generate `JobGraph`. `LocalFlinkMiniCluster` is the place for execution.

In last line, one can choose whether to wait the job or not (`submitJobDetached`).